# Oracle Apex - Apex Mail Send sending same email two times

Tags: oracle, oracle-apex

I have a button that runs the apex_mail.send functionality when clicked.
The code I have is the following:

```
DECLARE
l_body CLOB;
V_ID_MX number;
V_REQUESTER VARCHAR2(1000);
v_user varchar2(300);

BEGIN

--Basically selects the latest added row on my table:
SELECT max(id) INTO V_ID_MX FROM My_Table; 

--Line to remove the @mail.com from user email:
select INITCAP(replace(regexp_replace(rep_assigned,'@[a-zA-z0-9.]*',''), '.', ' '))  into 
v_user from My_table WHERE ID = V_ID_MX;

--Assigning Rep email to the v_requester variable:
select rep_assigned into V_REQUESTER from My_Table WHERE ID = V_ID_MX;

 
l_body := 'Hi ' || v_user ||',' || utl_tcp.crlf;
l_body := l_body || utl_tcp.crlf;
l_body := l_body || utl_tcp.crlf;
l_body := l_body || 'Please review latest added row.' ||utl_tcp.crlf;
l_body := l_body || utl_tcp.crlf;
l_body := l_body || 'ID: '|| V_ID_MX ||utl_tcp.crlf;
l_body := l_body || utl_tcp.crlf;
l_body := l_body || utl_tcp.crlf;
l_body := l_body || 'Thank you' || utl_tcp.crlf;

apex_mail.send(
    p_to   => V_REQUESTER, 
    p_from => 'generic_email@mail.com',
    p_body => l_body,
    p_subj => 'Some Subject';

END;
```

It works perfectly, with one annoying exception: it sends the same email twice.
Does anybody know how to avoid this email duplicity?

Thanks

Comment: try using pushing to queue by: apex_mail.push_queue;

Comment: This question has nothing do with with email - it is about a pl/sql process being executed twice. Take a step back. How is the pl/sql block being executed. Is it a dynamic action or a page process ? What are the conditions for it ? If it is a dynamic action and it has "Fire on page load" checked then that might be the cause. If it a page process then probably the conditions are not set correctly.

Comment: thank you Koen, that was it really. Thanks